# Can't output data from fetch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

In general, there is a Left page and the SearchFilms component function, so the problem is that I cannot pull out the result and get it and display it on the left page, the api of the key has been removed on purpose. I'm a beginner, so I don't know how and what to do.

```
import React, {Fragment, useEffect, useState} from "react";
import {Container, TextField, Typography} from "@material-ui/core";
import SearchFilms from "../companents/searchFilm";

export const Left = () =>{
    const [keyword, setKeyword] = useState ('')
    console.log(setKeyword)
    const [page, setPage] = useState(1)
    console.log(setPage)
    function  handleSearch(e) {
        setKeyword(e.target.value)
        setPage(1)
    }
    SearchFilms(keyword, page)

    return(
        <Fragment>
            <Container fixed style={{paddingTop: "9%"}}>
                <form className="" noValidate autoComplete="off">
                    <TextField id="outlined-basic" label="Поиск" variant="outlined" onChange={handleSearch}/>
                </form>

            </Container>
        </Fragment>
    )
}
```

```
import {useEffect, useState} from "react";
import {Typography} from "@material-ui/core";


export default function SearchFilms(keyword, page)  {
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);
    useEffect(() => {
        const headers = {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'X-API-KEY': '17d4a3d9-ab7d-4038-843b-8a95e22b6c7b'
        }
        fetch(`https://kinopoiskapiunofficial.tech/api/v2.1/films/search-by-keyword?keyword=${keyword}&page=${page}`, {method:'GET',headers:headers})
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => setData())
    }, [keyword, page])
    return (
        <div>{data}</div>
    )
}
```

Comment: you are missing to add data with `setData()`, Please focus on fetch method, within that just update this `setData()` to this `setData(data)`

Answer (score 2):

#### Setting state

You are not passing data to `setData`: `then(data => setData())`

Change to:

```
.then(data => setData(data))
```

#### Rendering

Also, if `data` is an array, you can't render it like {data}. You should map over it:

```
<div>
  {data.map((item, index) => (
    <p> {item} </p>
  )}
</div>
```

#### One additional thing:

You are not destructuring props: `export default function SearchFilms(keyword, page)`. By default React component gets one argument: `props`. If your props contain `keyword` and `page` keys, destructure them:

```
export default function SearchFilms({keyword, page})
```

#### One more additional thing:

You are not rendering your component `SearchFilms`. You can't call a react functional component like you do in: `SearchFilms(keyword, page)`

You should render it like:

```
return(
        <Fragment>
            ...
          <SearchFilms keyword={keyword} page={page} />
        </Fragment>
    )
```

Comment: I tried it, but I still can't output it, everything is fine in the console

Comment: Updated answer, take a look

Comment: @SinanYamen i added destructuring as you said it threw 400 error in console

Comment: Can you edit the question and include how you render <SearchFilms too?

Comment: I don't know, here is the SearchFilms function, and there is a left function, there is no rendering either there or there

Comment: Updated the question again, take a look. What are you trying to do by calling `SearchFilms(...)`

Comment: did everything as you said the page in the browser gives an error: "Error: SearchFilms (...): Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null."

Comment: This question has a lot of individual errors, I will make an example codesandbox and you can pick it up from there, I will comment the link once done.

Comment: Here is a [codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/hopeful-booth-0eexq?file=/src/Results.js). I tried to replicate your problem, I render the child as input changes, which fetches and displays data. Type 1 or 2 or 3 in the input to make `fetch` work

Comment: thanks, i complete my code